# How do I make a date with new Date() in javascript given information from an array in php?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, datetime

I am iterating through an array of elements in php and accessing each element through javascript. I want to compare dates, but in order to do that I have to take out the information I need to do a new Date() object. This is what the information looks like in php:

```
"0": {
.
.
.
"dateInfo": {
  "date": "2021-11-19 00:00:000000",
  "timezone_type": 3,
  "timezone: "UTC"
  },
.
.
.
},
```

I am accessing these from an array in javascript by doing:

```
array["0"]["dateInfo"]
```

I tried to take the just the year month and date and make that into a new Date() object by doing this:

```
var parts = array["0"]["dateInfo"]["date"].split('-');
var dateToComp = new Date(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
```

But when I did a `console.log(dateToComp);` it said it was an invalid date. My end goal to to compare this date with todays date to get something in the fashion:

```
var today = new Date()
var parts = array["0"]["dateInfo"]["date"].split('-');
var dateToComp = new Date(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);

if(dateToComp < today)
{
   return 0; // in the past
}
else
{
   return 1; // same day or future day
}
```

I hope what I am trying to say makes sense and any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You may want to double-check your values in javascript. The var_dump in PHP may not be what you're getting in javascript. `console.log(array["0"]["dateInfo"]);` to see what that contains.

Comment: If the date does contain what you think, then `parts[2]` won't. It will be `19 00:00:000000`

Comment: `$newDate = date( 'm/d/y g:i A', strtotime(array["0"]["dateInfo"]["date"]));`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
new Date(array["0"]["dateInfo"]["date"])
```

should work

Comment: The OP format is not supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent. `new Date("2021-11-19 00:00:000000")` produces an invalid Date in Safari at least, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: This worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

> But when I did a console.log(dateToComp); it said it was an invalid date.

Because `parts[2]` is "19 00:00:000000", which is an invalid date component. Instead split on any non–digit character `\D`. Also, you need to subtract 1 from the month.

E.g.

```js
let date = '2021-11-19 00:00:000000';
// Split on any non–digit character
let [y, m, d] = date.split(/\D/);
// Months are zero indexed
// Treat input as local
console.log(new Date(y, m-1, d).toString());
// Treat input as UTC
console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(y, m-1, d)).toISOString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateToComp = new Date(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2].split(' ')[0]);
```

Comment: @CinCout, please refrain from reviewing answers on technologies you're not familiar with. This answer is an honest attempt at answering the question. However, it is of low quality because it is a code-only answer. [SO]'s quality standards suggest code in answers should be accompanied by a brief explanation on why/how the code solves the problem.